# Writing and overwriting data to file (.csv)

Tags: r, shiny

is it possible to write data to .csv, without downloading it? There is a downloadButton and downloadHandler, but they write data and then downloads it.

If first thing is possible, is it possible to write data to csv and overwrite. For example, I have a .csv file with values and I want to change the values in that csv just overwriting them.

The idea is that, I want to store some values in the .csv which a loaded on start up. Even though, user wants to change some of them and save it for next time, therefore I need to change them. And next time altered values are loaded.

Comment: How do you want to change the values ? with a numeric Input ?

Comment: I want to change them by those which are selected with selectInput(). The idea is: I have a items list A and selectInput() renders with this list with none selected (when other .csv is empyt). After I select (and possibly hit some kind a button), the other file updates and writes down values which are selected, for example, a_2, a_5. On the next start up, items list A is again rendered, but this time items selected are from other file, so a_2 and a_5. And so forth

Comment: Ok. Can you provide the code of what you have tried so far please ?

Comment: I just came up with idea of solving this, I will post an answer myself later. Thanks for response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea**

The problem is that I would like allow user to select some option and shiny app should remember that options on the next application start up. Firstly, my idea was just to create empty variable on launch of app: `savedItems<-NULL`. All the time the app is hosted, I would add items like this `savedItems<<-c(savedItems,'a1','a3','a5')`. However, sometimes server, on which I will host, will be restarted, so `savedItems` would be again initialized as empty vector. Therefore, I decided to update my idea and save values not in vector, but in file.

**Updated Idea & Solution**

Firstly, I initialized empty .csv file, for example `upload.csv`, where I want to store data. I want to read this file each time I start application (not host), therefore firstly I just read my .csv, which will only save column vector in file:

`shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
       uselessRead <- read.table("upload.csv",header=FALSE)
       useless <<- as.vector(uselessRead[,1])
...`

Then, using `selectInput` I select some items and add them to my vector `useless`. I do this by following after clicking `actionButton("addUseless",...)`:

`observe({
    if (input$addUseless == 0)
      return ()
    }
    isolate({
      useless<<-input$uselessItems # from selectInput("uselessItems",...)
    })
  })`

After this, my vector is overwritten (if was populated) by new selected values. So, I want these values to appear in my `upload.csv`. So I do this after clicking `actionButton("upload",...)`:

`observe({
    if (input$upload == 0) {
      return ()
    }
    isolate ({
      write.table(useless,"upload.csv",
                 col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
    })
  })`

This will write (and overwrite everything what was inside) everything, what was assigned to `useless` vector.

On the next start up, my app will firstly read `upload.csv` so application which values should be selected and user don't have to do that every single time.